# Why is a newly created user account using my personal bashrc?

Tags: linux, bash, bashrc

I set up a home server running Rocky 9 with a minimal install and one user account [mine]. I then created a new user, but when I login as the new user, the bash prompt is using the custom PS1 scheme for my user, even though the `.bashrc` for the new user is all defaults with no special configuration.

How is this possible?

Comment: How exactly *did* you "log in as the new user" – and are you sure you're looking at the correct home directory?

Comment: Logging in as the user was just `sudo su {username}`, then `cd ~/` (it put me in my personal home directory on login) then `cat .bashrc`. So I think this is the correct bashrc?

Comment: It may be the correct .bashrc according to "home directory", but is the "home directory" **itself** correct? That is, did the `cd ~` put you in the correct place for the new user? Does `printenv HOME` output the correct path for the new user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, try `sudo su - {username}`, as that (`-`) is the parameter for `su` to simulate user login; without it, the home directory of the `sudoer` remains in use.

> -, -l, --login
> Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to
> a real login:
>
> ```
>        •   clears all the environment variables except TERM and
>            variables specified by --whitelist-environment
>
>        •   initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL, USER,
>            LOGNAME, and PATH
>
>        •   changes to the target user’s home directory
>
>        •   sets argv[0] of the shell to '-' in order to make the shell
>            a login shell
> ```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @rapsik Welcome on SuperUser. Try to add some references if you have time...

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Its odd, though, I've never had this happen on, say, a Fedora machine. Is there something that Fedora does under the hood that Rocky doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Both `sudo` and `su` reset the `$HOME` variable to the target user's home directory. If the new user is seeing the same `~/.bashrc` as yours then there are very few reasons to consider:

- You created the new user with the same home directory as yours (either directly or indirectly)
- At some point you copied your `.bashrc` into `/etc/skel`, where it's used to populate new users' home directories
- You didn't successfully execute the `sudo su` and you were unexpectedly still in your original user account
- Your custom shell prompt coincidentally matches the one defined for new users

You would need to compare the value of `$HOME` for your existing and new account, the content of the two users' `.bashrc` files along with the one in `/etc/skel`, and the output of `id` for both users to be able to derive a definitive answer.

Instead of `sudo su {username}` per [your comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1829845/why-is-a-newly-created-user-account-using-my-personal-bashrc/1829980#comment2885647_1829845), just use `sudo` directly:

```
sudo -iu {username}
```

The `-i` flag tells `sudo` to start a login shell, the `-u {username}` tells `sudo` to change to that user account. See `man sudo` for the documentation.

(There is never any need to use `sudo su` as `sudo` itself is perfectly capable.)